# Suppress Netsuite Internal ID column in saved search result

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I have "Show Internal IDs" turned on in my Netsuite general preferences, but have one saved search where I don't want the internal ID column to be part of the results.  Is there a way to suppress the internal ID column on a search-by-search basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no search level setting to turn the feature off, but there is a fairly hacky workaround that might suit your purpose.  When you aggregate or summarize results, only columns with summary settings are shown.  So simply Group each column in your search to suppress the display of Internal ID.  There may be some columns that can't be grouped; just make these Min or Max.  There should only be one result per "group" which you can verify by running the search before and after grouping.

Comment: Thanks.  I do love a hacky answer, and this likely would have worked, but all my fields are "Formula (Text)" fields, and since, when I group, I have to sort by one of them, this isn't working.  I'll keep it in mind for the future.